# Could you explain the definition of mesh?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, meshing

For the context, I have seen various definitions, like this:
[image]

Or this:

[image]

I would like to concentrate to the first one (Definition 19.) and understand this definition. I think mesh there is supremum of some metric stuff. However, I don´t know, what is "diam $U$". Could you answer this, please?

Also, have you seen this definition of mesh, or different definitions?

Comment: $\mathrm{diam}\;U=\sup\{d(x,y)\mid x,y\in U\}$ measures how far two points in $U$ can be. When $U$ is a nice closed geometrical shape this agrees with the usual notion of diameter from geometry

Comment: [Do not use MathJax to italicize the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @user10354138 I imagine Tereza's intent was to type $\mathrm{mesh}$ rather than italicize.

Comment: @MarkS. Still against guideline though.  Do not use MathJax for text formatting in title (or anywhere really), full-stop.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry, I just wanted to make it look different from the other text I guess. Next time I know the guidelines. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mesh is simply the length of the largest sub-interval.

Example: If we divide the interval $[1,2]$ into sub-intervals $[1,1.5]$, $[1.5,2]$, $[2,3]$, then the mesh is equal to $1$, which is the length of the longest (last in this case) sub-interval.

Note that, by length of $[x,y]$, we mean, $|y-x|$.

Comment: Not sure that $[2,3]$ is a subinterval of $[1,2]$

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{diam} U$ is short for [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Diameter_of_a_metric_space). So the mesh is the smallest number where all the diameters of things in $\mathcal{U}$ are less than it.

Note: If you can't read the box above, remember to follow https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35899/491852

Answer (score 2):

The concept of mesh is usually studied in relation with the partition of a closed interval in Riemann Integration. It is the length of the largest sub-interval included in the partition. If the sub-intervals happen to be of equal size, the mesh will the length of any sub-interval.

Usually, for R-integrability, the mesh is desired to be arbitrarily small.